# How to reorder a list composed of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I am trying to tranform

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2]]
```

*into*

```
[[1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1], [2, 3, 1], [1, 2], [2, 1]]
```

But instead of the correct output, I am getting this:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [1, 2]]
```

Here is my code

```
def listReorder(list1):
List2 = []
for list in list1:
    listTemp = list
    for item in list:
        List2.append(listTemp)
        t=listTemp.pop()
        listTemp.insert(0, t)
return List2

List = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2]]
listReorder(List)
```

Comment: `listTemp = list` **does not create a copy**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your for loop, you are adding the same list again and again, but instead, you should make a copy of the list in the iteration.

```py
def listReorder(list1):
    List2 = []
    for list in list1:
        listTemp = list
        for item in list:
            List2.append([x for x in listTemp])
            t=listTemp.pop()
            listTemp.insert(0, t)
    return List2

List = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2]]
listReorder(List)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [3, 1, 2], [2, 3, 1], [1, 2], [2, 1]]
```

Comment: So the 'reference' is not turned into a list til the end of the loop, do I understand correctly?

Comment: @ShawnCheung Actually, the reference is `listTemp` but using `[x for x in listTemp]` we are generating a copy of `listTemp` and adding that to `List2`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga answer updated!

Comment: So, Python's evaluation strategy is named "call by sharing" (first coined for the CLU programming language, created by Barbara Liskov of the Liskov Substitution Principle fame, a highly influential language), but that term is highly academic and other terms are used more widely. But if you want a good description of the differences, see this excellent blog post: https://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/